# invalid use of non-static data member with vector

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, return, non-static

I'm trying to access to class function from vector cell

```
class Cookie
{
    int Integer = 10;
    struct Structure
    {
        int& getInteger()
        {
            return Integer; // ERROR invalid use of non-static data member
        }
    };
    vector<Structure> Vector;
}
```

I'm stuck on this issue. Please help

Comment: How do you expect the `struct` to know which instance of `Cookie` to access?

Comment: [Looks like an X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Outline your real goal and odds are someone can provide a solution or suggestion that is possible.

Comment: The error message is unhelpful in this case. Did you intend that Integer should be a member of Structure? You have it as a member of Cookie. The compiler error is telling you that while Structure has special visibility of Cookie, it can't access the members without a Cookie pointer.